# How to add form data to the database after successful Stripe payment

Tags: typescript, next.js

So I have a web page which has a form. On submit the user is redirected to the Stripe's checkout page.
However I want to store that form data but ONLY if the payment is successful.
I can know if the payment is successful by using Stripe's webhooks, but I don't know how to get the form data in the webhook.

This is the submit function for the form:

```
// data: the data of the form passed by react hook form
async function onSubmit(data: any) {  
    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/payment', {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        priceId: '<price_id>',
        eventData: {
          // the form data
           data 
        }
      })
    });

    const resData = await res.json();

    if(res.ok) {
      // Redirects to Stripe's checkout page
      router.push(resData)
    }
  }
```

This is the Next.js's route handler for handling the Stripe checkout.
I can get here the data from the request, but I don't want to store it yet as the checkout/payment is not yet completed/successful.

```
export async function POST(req: Request) {
  const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET!);
  const data = await req.json();
  const { priceId } = data;

  // here i can access the data, but the payment is still not completed, so I don't want to store to the database yet.
  const { eventData } = data;

  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    line_items: [
      {
        price: priceId,
        quantity: 1
      }
    ],
    mode: 'payment',
    success_url: 'http://localhost:3000/payment/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
    cancel_url: 'http://localhost:3000',
  });

  return NextResponse.json(session.url)
}
```

This is the webhook that lets me know whether the payment is successful or not and I don't know how to get the form data and save it to the database.

```
export async function POST(request: Request, response: Response) {
  const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET!);
  const body = await request.json();

  const sig: any = request.headers.get('stripe-signature');

  let event;

  try {
    event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(body, sig, process.env.WEBHOOK_SECRET!);
  } catch (err) {
      return NextResponse.json({
        status: 400,
        err
      })
  }

  // Handle the event
  switch (event.type) {
    case 'checkout.session.completed':
        // Am I supposed to do something here???
      break;
    default:
      console.log(`Unhandled event type ${event.type}`);
  }

  return NextResponse.json({
    status: 200
  });
}
```

I have been experimenting with the code above and did research online but couldn't find anything.
I want to store the form data ONLY AFTER the payment is complete and successful